# How to find max value for Double and Float in Swift

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, double, infinity

Current learning Swift, there are ways to find *max* and *min* value for different kind of **Integer** like `Int.max` and `Int.min`.

Is there a way to find max value for Double and Float? Moreover, which document should I refer for this kind of question? I am currently reading Apple's **The Swift Programming Language**.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

As of Swift 3+, you should use:

```
CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

Comment: This is the answer if you are interested in your code compiling on Linux too.

Answer (score 75):

While there’s no `Double.max`, it is defined in the C `float.h` header, which you can access in Swift via `import Darwin`.

```
import Darwin

let fmax = FLT_MAX
let dmax = DBL_MAX
```

These are roughly `3.4 * 10^38` and `1.79 * 10^308` respectively.

But bear in mind it’s not so simple with floating point numbers (it’s never simple with floating point numbers). When holding numbers this large, you lose precision in a similar way to losing precision with very small numbers, so:

```
let d = DBL_MAX
let e = d - 1.0
let diff = d - e
diff == 0.0  // true

let maxPlusOne = DBL_MAX + 1
maxPlusOne == d  // true

let inf = DBL_MAX * 2
// perhaps infinity is the “maximum” 
inf == Double.infinity  // true
```

So before you get into some calculations that might possibly brush up against these limits, you should probably read up on floating point.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/) are probably a good start.

Comment: I am try you code in Xcode playground and get `(+infinity)` for Double and 340,282,346,638,529,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.0 for Float. Why Double and Int64 both have 64bit but double can store more numbers?

Comment: You need to learn about floating point representation.  Start with the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and also [this intro](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/)

Comment: For the common case of using max/min values with comparison operators DBL_MAX will always give valid results.

Comment: Deprecated in Swift 3, it's now `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude`

Answer (score 11):

AV's answer is fine, but I find those macros hard to remember and a bit non-obvious, so eventually I made `Double.MIN` and friends work:

```
extension Double {
    static var MIN     = -DBL_MAX
    static var MAX_NEG = -DBL_MIN
    static var MIN_POS =  DBL_MIN
    static var MAX     =  DBL_MAX
}
```

Don't use lowercase min and max -- those symbols are used in Swift 3.

Answer (score 7):

Just write

```
let mxFloat = MAXFLOAT
```

You will get the maximum value of a float in Swift.

Comment: This will not compile on linux

Answer (score 4):

Also `CGFloat.infinity`, `Double.infinity` or just `.infinity` can be useful in such situations.

Answer (score 3):

Works with **swift 5**

```
public extension Double {

    /// Max double value.
    static var max: Double {
        return Double(greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    }

    /// Min double value.
    static var min: Double {
        return Double(-greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    }
}
```