# What is the maximum value that can be stored as a Double without losing precision in Swift?

Tags: swift, double

According to Swift, the greatest finite magnitude that can be stored as a `Double` is much more than that of `Int`.

```
print(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude) // 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

However, the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28525484/8330469) question says that you may lose precision while storing large values.

So, what is the maximum value that can be saved as a Double without losing precision?

Comment: Is this a real world problem or are you just curious? Either way, did you read the articles linked to in the answer you linked to?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to calculate very long factorials. There is a limitation in using Int. This great answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/43830151/8330469 gives the solution. But, if Double can store very large values, we can calculate large factorials more easily. I had a cursory look at the articles but I didn't go deep. The articles are too deep and right now I can't go so deep. So, I decided to put this as a question here. It may help others in future as well who may be constrained by time to do thorough research on floats and hence may seek answers in Stackoverflow. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: A `Double` is good for 15 or 16 significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
UInt64(2) << Double.significandBitCount
```

i.e. 2^53.

i.e. 9,007,199,254,739,992.

Swift `Double`s follow [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which specifies that they have a mantissa¹ of 52 explicit bits plus 1 implicit bit (always 0b1 for normal-form doubles).

All integers with that magnitude or less are represented perfectly within `Double`; there is no loss in converting them between `UInt64` and `Double`.

---

¹ Sometimes referred to as the "significand", as in Swift's `Double` API.

Comment: That does not appear to be the largest `Double`. For example, `9_999_999_999_999_998` is safely stored in a `Double` and can be converted back to `UInt64` without any loss.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure that's what the original question is after.  In the comments the OP talked about wanting to calculate factorials (accurately), and going higher than 2^53 in a `Double` will risk introducing rounding errors.  For that purpose, I doubt it's useful to know that a scattered few specific values (beyond 2^53) happen to roundtrip from `Double` to integer losslessly.

Comment: Using Double is worse than UInt64 for calculating accurate factorial. Just not enough precision.